# Finding position on a slanted line

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I've been looking for an equation to find where the X value collides with a slanted line, and I have been rather unsuccessful and would appreciate some help.

That was probably pretty unclear but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Smo5.png) picture should make it more clear.

I'm pretty new to calculating with slanted lines/hypotenuses so please try to keep it understandable.

Comment: You want to find the intersection point of the two lines. But what is the equation of the green line?

Comment: The green line is just a straight line along the X axis

Comment: Draw some similar right triangles and work out their proportions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the two points $(2,2)$ and $(-1,-2)$ you can find the straight line equation :

$$\frac{y-2}{2-(-2)} = \frac{x-2}{2-(-1)}$$

The equation of the line is :
$$y=\frac{4}{3}x - \frac{2}{3}$$

Now the intersection of this line with the green line which is $y=0$ can be found out by putting $y=0$ in the straight line equation.

You will get the point as $(\frac{1}{2},0)$

Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we want the equation of the blue line. It passes through points $(-1, -2)$ and $(2,2)$ so therefore its slope is
$$
k = \frac{2-(-2)}{2-(-1)} = \frac{4}{3}
$$
The line is of the form $y=kx + b$, so we need $2=\frac{4}{3}\times 2 +b \Rightarrow b = \frac{-2}{3}$. Therefore, the blue line has the equation
$$
y = \frac{4x-2}{3}
$$
Now we want to solve $y=0$, or
$$
\frac{4x-2}{3} = 0 \qquad  \Rightarrow \qquad  4x-2 = 0 \qquad  \Rightarrow  \qquad x=\frac{1}{2}
$$